# ExpressibleByCustomTypeLiteral

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Why there is no such a protocol?
Of course it make cense only when CustomType itself conforms to some of ExpressibleBySomeLiteral protocol.

```
struct First: ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral {
    let data: [String: Int]
    
    init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (String, Int)...) {
        data = .init(uniqueKeysWithValues: elements)
    }
}

let f: First = ["one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3]

struct Second: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral {
    let firsts: [First]
    
    init(arrayLiteral elements: First...) {
        firsts = elements
    }
}

let s: Second = [["one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3],
                 ["four": 4, "five": 5],
                 ["six": 6, "seven": 7, "eight": 8, "nine": 9]]
```

All the code above is absolutely valid, compiles and works perfectly.
But when we try to do in the same way something more simple, turns out it's impossible:

```
struct SimplifiedSecond: ExpressibleCustomTypeLiteral {
    let first: First

    init(customTypeLiteral element: First) {
        first = element
    }
}

let s: SimplifiedSecond = ["one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3]
```

Comment: Well, I (and the swift compiler) know what a dictionary literal is, but not what a "custom type literal" is. What on earth is a "custom type literal"?

Comment: From your usage, it looks to me that `SimplifiedSecond` should also conform to `ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral`. The initialiser should be implemented as `first = First(dictionaryLiteral: elements)`. Don't you agree?

Comment: @Sweeper In the example "struct Second: ExpressibleByArrayLiteral" compiler successfully deals with Array[CustomType], so why can't it manages just CustomType stuff?

Comment: Do you realise that `["one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3]` is not a `First` literal? It's a dictionary literal. In fact, there are no `First` literals. If you want to implicitly convert from _any_ value of type `First` to `Second`, then this is against one of the design goals of Swift, which is to limit implicit type conversions as much as possible.

Comment: @Sweeper "it looks to me that SimplifiedSecond should also conform to ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral" You're right. I think this is a solution. Very simple but not obvious. Can you please post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to do this:

```
let s: SimplifiedSecond = ["one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3]
```

`["one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3]` is not a `First` *literal*. `First` literals do not exist. There is a fixed set of literals defined by the grammar of the language, which you can find [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html#ID414).

`["one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3]` is a dictionary literal, so `SimplifiedSecond` should conform to `ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral` instead:

```
struct SimplifiedSecond: ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral {
    let first: First

    init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (String, Int)...) {
        first = First(dictionaryLiteral: elements)
    }
}
```